# Best way to run a script for large userbase?

Tags: node.js, database

I have users stored in postgresql database (~10 M) and i want to send all of them emails.
Currently i have written a nodejs script which basically fetches users 1000 at a time (Offset and limit in sql)  and queues the request in rabbit MQ. Now this seems clumsy to me, as if the node process fails at any time i have to restart the process (i am currently keeping track of number of users skipped per query, and can restart back at the previous number skipped found from logs). This might lead to some users receiving duplicate email and some not receiving any. I can create a new table with new column indicating whether email has been to that person or not, but in my current situation i cant do so. Neither can i create a new table nor can i add a new row to existing table. (Seems to me like idempotent problem?).
How would you approach this problem? Do you think compound indexes might help. Please explain.

Comment: Added the PostgreSQL tag and removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag from your question, although the answer might not be specific to a given DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is indeed to store who received an email, so there's no chance of doing it twice.

If you can't add tables or columns to your existing database, just create a new database for this purpose. If you want to be able to recover from crashes, you will need to store who got the email *somewhere* so if you are given hard restrictions on not storing this in your main database, get creative with another storage mechanism.